# Posible funcionamiento irregular del módulo re en Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Se dispone de la siguiente estructura de etiquetas HTML (extracto de otro documento más grande):

```
texto = '''
                <div id="breadcrumb_feature_div" data-feature-name="breadcrumb" data-template-name="breadcrumb" class="a-section a-spacing-none feature t-prnt t-full">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        #a-page .dp-breadcrumb .breadcrumb-inline-links {
                            display: inline;
                        }

                        .dp-breadcrumb {
                            31.25px;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <div class="a-section a-spacing-large">
                        <h4 class="a-spacing-small">Estás aquí</h4>
                        <div class="a-section dp-breadcrumb">
                            <div aria-live="polite" data-a-expander-collapsed-height="125" class="a-expander-collapsed-height a-row a-expander-container a-expander-partial-collapse-container" style="max-height:125px; _height:125px">
                                <div aria-expanded="false" class="a-expander-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content">
                                    <a class="a-spacing-base a-link-normal" href=''>departamentos</a>
                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=''>Tienda Kindle</a>
                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=''>eBooks Kindle</a>
                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=''>Deportes</a>
                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=''>Ciclismo</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="a-expander-header a-expander-partial-collapse-header"><a href='' data-action="a-expander-toggle" class="a-declarative" data-a-expander-toggle="{&quot;allowLinkDefault&quot;:true, &quot;expand_prompt&quot;:&quot;Mostrar más&quot;, &quot;collapse_prompt&quot;:&quot;Mostrar menos&quot;}"><i class="a-icon a-icon-extender-expand"></i><span class="a-expander-prompt">Mostrar más</span></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="returnPolicy_feature_div" data-feature-name="returnPolicy" data-template-name="returnPolicy" class="a-section a-spacing-none feature t-prnt t-full">
                </div>
                <div class="aw-campaigns"></div>
'''
```

Se pretende extraer las 4 etiquetas que contienen las clases `a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links`.

Por motivos que no vienen al caso, **se considera que el documento HTML original está roto (por lo cual se descarta el uso de librerías de parseo como BeautifulSoup)** y se plantea como solución el uso de expresiones regulares, de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> import re
>>> z = re.findall(r'^[^\n]+a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links[^\n]+$', texto)
>>> z
[]
>>>
```

**El resultado que obtenemos es una lista vacía** (no se encuentran coincidencias), **pero cuando acudimos a un validador de expresiones regulares** como [éste](https://regex101.com/), sí obtenemos el resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué la expresión regular sí produce el resultado esperado en el validador, y no lo hace al ser implementada mediante el módulo `re`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay ningún malfuncionamiento, la causa de que no encuentre coincidencias es mucho más simple. El problema es que no tienes activado el modificador [`MULTILINES`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) que el validador online tiene activado por defecto.

Esto hace que las anclas `^` y `$` coincidan al principio y final de cada línea respectivamente, en lugar de comenzar y finalizar en la cadena completa.

```
import re


patt = re.compile(
    r'^[^\n]+a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links[^\n]+$',
    re.MULTILINE
    )
z = patt.findall(texto)
```

> ```
> >>> z
> ['                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=\'\'>Tienda Kindle</a>',
>  '                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=\'\'>eBooks Kindle</a>',
>  '                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=\'\'>Deportes</a>',
>  '                                    <a class="a-size-base a-link-child breadcrumb-inline-links" href=\'\'>Ciclismo</a>']
> ```

Comment: Ni se me pasaba por la cabeza que el resultado de aplicar una expresión regular dependiera de los modificadores y no de la expresión regular como tal. ¡Muchas gracias!